# Showing Time line using d3js

Tags: javascript, datetime, d3.js

I am new to d3js, trying to display a graph with X axis having time series, 00:00 to 23:59. 
Trying to configure d3js to parse time as below

```
var parseTime = d3.time.format("%H%M").parse;
var mytime = "2045"; // I expect it to be 8 45 PM
mytime = parseTime(mytime);
alert(JSON.stringify(mytime));
```

But the alert shows "1900-01-01T15:15:00.000Z" instead of 20:45. I know something is terribly wrong, may be my understanding itself is wrong.

Any pointers to have timeseries data on x series would be helpful.

Comment: Works for me. I'm getting "1900-01-01T20:45:00.000Z". Maybe a timezone issue (are you UTC-5)?

Comment: Oh may be my question was misleading, how do i show only time on the x-axis, i.e 00:00 01:30 02:00 etc.

Comment: Have a look at the [time scales documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Scales).

Answer (score 0):

Try to add .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%H%M")) in your x-axis declaration.

For a more general explanation of tickformat you can read this post:
https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/9764126